# Find frequency of sinusoidal fit to a data which covers only part of a period

Tags: least-squares

I am trying to fit a general Sinusoidal curve on a set of data points with following features:

1. Data covers only part of the period
2. Data points are not equally distanced apart

What would be the best way to approximate the frequency in this specific case? In all the cases I saw, data usually covered several periods, for example, I was trying to use this method:https://www.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales# (page 24) which somehow linearises the problem of finding the frequency by using integrals. However, it does not give me any good results. And neither does ChatGPT lol.

What is the best strategy for approximating frequency in this particular case? I would also like to avoid iterative approaches (I.E. Gradient descent)

Thank you very much for your answers and help!

EDIT: As asked, the data set can be found in this[Desmos Graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dkundykcak).

Personal Edit by Jean Marie :
If it can help, here is the data array :

151.73378 -7.66837

151.71739 -7.6667

151.69138 -7.65908

151.62711 -7.6494

151.57689 -7.64485

151.52066 -7.63923

151.46477 -7.63805

151.42001 -7.63621

151.35583 -7.63503

151.30501 -7.63482

151.26636 -7.63555

151.19527 -7.63998

151.14746 -7.64203

151.08684 -7.64768

151.03366 -7.65429

150.99374 -7.65947

150.9238 -7.66734

150.87398 -7.67575

150.81732 -7.68646

150.76454 -7.69704

150.7218 -7.70754

150.66092 -7.72259

150.60757 -7.73582

150.55692 -7.74901

150.50587 -7.76589

150.45662 -7.78243

150.39748 -7.80429

150.34641 -7.82432

150.30864 -7.83916

150.24689 -7.86442

150.19942 -7.8852

150.14586 -7.9092

150.09666 -7.93266

150.05682 -7.95329

149.99934 -7.98415

149.95216 -8.0112

149.903 -8.04024

149.85516 -8.07024

149.81479 -8.09681

149.7623 -8.12986

149.71567 -8.16173

149.68178 -8.18646

149.6265 -8.22563

149.58386 -8.25824

149.53705 -8.29439

149.49318 -8.32941

149.45874 -8.36022

149.40773 -8.40409

149.36754 -8.44096

149.326 -8.48096

149.28476 -8.52128

149.25078 -8.55716

149.207 -8.60217

149.1693 -8.64357

149.13908 -8.67568

149.0923 -8.72745

149.05728 -8.76954

149.02003 -8.81639

148.98415 -8.86092

148.95917 -8.89317

148.91348 -8.95282

148.88315 -8.99699

148.8477 -9.04725

148.81738 -9.09368

148.78664 -9.14241

148.75612 -9.19128

148.72556 -9.2432

148.6987 -9.2938

148.67188 -9.3461

148.64496 -9.3996

148.61932 -9.45188

148.59395 -9.50262

148.57225 -9.54007

148.55563 -9.56308

148.53592 -9.56818

Comment: Have you considered using Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT, alias FFT) ? It is possible to adapt it to non uniform sampling.

Comment: Could you post a data set ? Also precise the model you want to fit

Comment: I added the data set (Can also send it in txt format if needed). By model you mean what? I would like to fit Sinusoidal curve in the most accurate way possible. If I am correct, this problem corresponds to approximating the frequency of the sinusoidal fit, since then the rest of the problem is just least-square.

Comment: Please answer my question. Is it because you have very few data that you don't use FFT ?

Comment: I am sorry. Yes, the number of data points in general is bellow 100, and since it covers only part of the period and the points are not necessarily equidistant, I am afraid that the approximation will not be the best. Or am I wrong in this case @JeanMarie? Thank you very much for the answers

Comment: With this amount of data, say above 50 you can attempt to use the FFT, but it is likely that no "true peak" can be extracted...

Comment: @Donatas Šimeliūna . You said that the method of fitting using integral equation "does not give me any good results". But are you sure to correctly apply this method ? Could you joint to your question an example of data ( numerical, not graphical ) to which the fitting seems failing.

Comment: @Donatas Šimeliūnas. Since you don'tt joint to your question the axample with the "not good results" I suppose that you made a mistake. So I don't go for further investigation. Or may be the problem is solved.

Comment: @JJacquelin. Do you by chance know how to recover the data ? Thanks and cheers :-)

Comment: @JeanMarie. Do you by chance know how to recover the data ? Thanks and cheers :-)

Comment: Could you send my the data on a .txt file ? My e-mail address is in my profile.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Do you mean the data which is in Fig. 1 of the text or in the desmos representation ?

Comment: @JeanMarie. The ones which are in Desmos.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici. Hi Claude ! Sorry, I don't know how to extract the data from Desmos. For me the link to Desmos  is of no true utility. Cheers.

Comment: @JJacquelin. Hi Jean ! Don(t worry. Jean-Marie did it. Thanks and cheers.

Comment: @JeanMarie. Do you use a specific application to extract data from Desmos ? Cheers.

Comment: @JJacquelin In fact no. I have extracted it entry by entry...

Comment: @JeanMarie. This is phenomenal amount of work ! I take my hat off. Would you like to share the data file if Donatas Šimeliūnas doesn't publish it ?

Comment: @JJacquelin Of course. Give me your e-mail address.

Comment: @JeanMarie. Thank you very much. But I prefer to not give my e-mail address on the web.

Comment: @JJacquelin I understand. I am going to add it (momentarily) as a personal edit to this question.

Comment: @JeanMarie. Very well. I got your data. This will help me to post an answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Interestingly enough a [cosh model](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/khb7ad9pvu) has $R^2=0.9998$ while the original only has $R^2=0.9961$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difficulty to fit a sine function in this case is that the points are located only on a very small segment which very badly defines a sine curve. In other words they are infinity many different convenient sine functions. The problem is almost indeterminate.

Whatever the method of fitting used the calculus involves inverse matrix computations. In case of almost indeterminate problem the determinant of the matrix becomes very close to zero. This is often the cause of inaccurate calculus.

As a  consequence very small differences in the numerical caculus will cause big difference of results (which all give the same quality of fitting). So the calculus have to be carried out with as much digits as possible and without roundings.

The accuracy of numerical calculus is improved with a preliminary shift $s$ of $x$ so that $|x-s|$ be small. For example with $s=148$ one get $|x-s|<4$ instead of $148<x<152$. This makes a big difference of magnitude of the values involved in the matrix calculus.

RESULTS : One observe that on a large range of the parameter $\omega$ the fitted curve is the same (blue curve on the graph). The Mean Square Error are very close one to the others. So (without more information about the problem) it is practicaly impossible to chose a solution among the infinity many solutions.

Note that the various sine curves coincide only on the range of the points. Outside this range the sine curves are very different one to the others because the $\omega$  are different.

[image]

In doing this I was following the method proposed by Claude Leibovici. This is a valuable method in general. But in the present case one cannot find a clear minimum of MSE. Nethertheless this method has a great advantage : It shows that many solutions exist. That is much better than the various methods of non-linear fitting which gives only one (almost arbitrary) solution without drawing attention to the quite indetermination aspect of the problem.

Fitting with a linear integral equation :

The details of the calculus with the software MATHCAD is shown below.

Data $x$ is replace by data $(x-s)$ with $s=148$.

The method from https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales pp.25-26 is applied.

We get $\omega^2<0$ which gives an imaginary $\omega$. This isn't surprising in case of almost indeterminate problem. In this case let :
$$\omega=i\:\lambda\quad ;\quad \sin(\omega x)=i\sinh(\lambda x)\quad ;\quad \cos(\omega x)=\cosh(\lambda x)$$
The sine equation model is transformed into an hyperbolic equation model. Finally the fitting is better.

[image]

[image]

The non-limear regression is an iterative process staring from "guessed" initial values of the parameters. Especially in the present case of almost indeterminate problem good initial values are necessary. The guess was not easy. Fortunately the values already obtained from the method with integral equation can be used as initial values.

Note that very good fitting and much simpler can be obtained with polynomial equation model.

Comment: I am sorry, I had forgotten the thread for some time. Thank you for this valuable answer! In the end indeed I had proceeded by trying to make a simple least square polynomial fit, and then try to deduce the frequency of sinusoidal from it (also least square method) and then perform a Newtonian algorithm. It worked for this case, but not for others, because, as you mentioned, its a very numerically unstable procedure!

Answer (score 1):

You have $n$ data points $(x_i,y_i)$ and you want to fit the model
$$y=a\sin(bx+c)+d$$ which is highly non linear.

Expand the sine and let
$$\alpha=a\sin(c) \qquad \text{and} \qquad \beta=a \cos(c)$$ to make
$$y=\alpha \cos(bx)+\beta \sin(bx)+d$$

If $b$ were known, the problem would  just be a bilinear regression using $t_i=\cos(bx_i)$ and $u_i=\sin(bx_i)$.

So, consider the sum of squares as a function of $b$. Try different values untill you see more or less a minimum. At this point, you have good estimates of $(b,\alpha,\beta,d)$ and you can safely run a nonlinear regression or even a Newton-Raphson procedure for two variables only since $d$ is implicitely known.